# Linux command line based Word Processors?

Tags: software

I am on the hunt for software options that may have gotten drowned out in my google searches by emacs, vim, and wordgrinder to use as a word processor in a Raspbian Terminal environment.

The goal has been to have a 'minimal distraction' writing environment running on a lightweight raspberry pi configured with little else. A little portable laptop that I can't easily "wander away from what I'm doing" because it never gets configured for things like checking email or browsing the web.

[And working on this project totally hasn't been used as procrastination from actually writing...]

---

Key Requirements:

- Must run natively in a linux command line environment. [System will not boot into a GUI/Windowed environment.]
- Must not rely on any closed encoding for file storage, not worried about extra markup/down added to the files, but ideally would want to be able to extract my information with a standard text editor.
- Plays nicely with a portrait monitor.

Nice to haves:

- Robust Spell Check with easy to configure custom dictionaries. [Different projects will draw on different technical jargon, sci-fi/fantasy, etc, and I would rather not cross pollute projects.]
- File Switching/Grouping controls for jumping between docs and maintaining organization of 'open stuff', while being able to move the whole process into the background as a single instance.
- Wiki-Like data organization for keeping track of notes.

---

Existing software opinions:

vim/emacs tends to feel like it has too much fluff in the UI to work through, or I end up tinkering with configs more than writing.

wordgrinder has a few quirks so far, with one of the biggest being lack of tab, and keeping data entry awkwardly in the 'middle' of the screen. [Which kind of negates the use of a portrait monitor when the software insists on not using much of it, given that the majority of my writing is appending to file rather than editing.]

---

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: Not sure if its lightweight enough for this, but could try [Scrivener on Linux?](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33)

Comment: I recently found out about [Software recs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), maybe they could help?

Comment: @AdamJLimbert: That would violate the requirement of no GUI.

Comment: Emacs has too much fluff?  I...I don't know what to say to that.  I used it for years, long past the time that pretty much everybody else had pretty graphics available.  I read my email via telnet into a UNIX shell and only emacs would do.  It meets all your requirements as far as I can tell.  This is in a comment because I'm not giving you an answer...you've rejected emacs, which is your right (even if it's the best non-GUI editor ever, not that I'm biased).

Answer (score 2):

I personaly prefer in the command line text editor "joe". It works nicely in raspbian, and it is very easy to use. If you keep forgeting keystrokes, just remember: ctrl-k-h and help appears.

```
apt-get install joe
```

Answer (score 2):

[NaNo editor](https://www.nano-editor.org/)

Strengths:

It handles text files.

It runs natively in Linux, and it has a prettier interface compared to vim.

It can also do spell checking after installing 'spell'.

It has a GNU licence